# How to push objects to a static vector while in the contructor of a class in C++

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, vector, constructor

I need to get in a vector the names of some cities as soon as they are created... In order to accomplish that I created a static `vector` for the class `City`, however when I try to compile my code I get the error

```
error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand
          this->cities.push_back(&this);
                                   ^~~~
```

What am I doing wrong?

My code is the following...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class City
{
private:
     string name;
     static vector<City *> cities;

public:
     string getName() { return name; }
     City(string name) : name{name}
     {
          this->cities.push_back(&this);
     };
     ~City(){};
} hongKong{"Hong Kong"}, bangkok{"Bangkok"}, macau{"Macau"}, singapura{"Singapura"}, londres{"Londres"}, paris{"Paris"}, dubai{"Dubai"}, delhi{"Delhi"}, istambul{"Istambul"}, kuala{"Kuala"}, lumpur{"Lumpur"}, novaIorque{"Nova Iorque"}, antalya{"Antalya"}, mumbai{"Mumbai"}, shenzen{"Shenzen"}, phuket{"Phuket"};

int main()
{
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should store the object itself in the vector, not the pointer. Also`City::cities.push_back` is correct.

Comment: `this` is already a `City*`.  You don't need the `&`.

Comment: @StephenNewell... Well if a try to do that, I gety the following error:
undefined reference to `Cidade::cidades'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Two problems: `cities` is static, so `this->` isn't necessary when referring to it.  Second, `this` is already a `City*`, so `&this` is a `City**`

Comment: @Breno what is `Cidade`? There is no mention of `Cidade` in the code you have shown.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I aam sorry that is the former name of the City class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is already a `City*` pointer, so drop the `&` from `&this`.

Also, don't forget to actually *define* the static `vector` object.

Also, you should account for the class' copy/move constructors and destructor, to make sure you don't miss adding pointers, or leave behind dangling pointers.

Try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class City
{
private:
     string name;
     static vector<City *> cities;

public:
     string getName() { return name; }

     City(string name) : name{name}
     {
          cities.push_back(this);
     }

     City(const City &src) : name{src.name}
     {
          cities.push_back(this);
     }

     City(City &&src) : name{std::move(src.name)}
     {
          cities.push_back(this);
     }

     ~City()
     {
          cities.erase(std::find(cities.begin(), cities.end(), this));
     }
};

vector<City *> City::cities;

City hongKong{"Hong Kong"}, bangkok{"Bangkok"}, macau{"Macau"}, singapura{"Singapura"}, londres{"Londres"}, paris{"Paris"}, dubai{"Dubai"}, delhi{"Delhi"}, istambul{"Istambul"}, kuala{"Kuala"}, lumpur{"Lumpur"}, novaIorque{"Nova Iorque"}, antalya{"Antalya"}, mumbai{"Mumbai"}, shenzen{"Shenzen"}, phuket{"Phuket"};

int main()
{
}
```